# Проблема с кодировкой при парсинге

Tags: php, кодировка, парсер

Я написал парсер сайта [planetestate](http://planetestate.com.ua).
При вытаскивании данных из "некоторых тегов", на "некоторых страницах", вместо нужного текста отображаются знаки вопросов.
[ВОТ](https://planetestate.com.ua/estate/13371?cat=sell) одна из таких страниц. На ней, после парсинга, вместо "грн" отображается "???", также на этой странице вместо заголовка "Продається Житловий будинок" выводится "?????????? ???????? ???????" и почему-то не вытаскиваются данные из таблиц с детальной информацией, такой как "КІМНАТ 3 | ЗАГАЛЬНА    87.4 м2 | ЖИТЛОВА   51.4 м2".
Кодировка сбита не только на символах кириллицы, но и на цифрах(например на цене и кредите). Таких объявлений (с плохой кодировкой) 221, всего спарсено 8873 объявления.
Пример парсинга цены объекта и валюты в которой указана цена.

```
function parseAd($html) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->encoding = "UTF-8";
    @$dom->loadHTML($html);
        $objInfo = $dom->getElementById("objInfo");
        ...
        $strongObjs = $objBuy->getElementsByTagName("strong");
        $em = $strongObjs->item(0)->getElementsByTagName("em");
        if ($em->length > 0) { // currency
            $currency = str_replace(chr(0xC2).chr(0xA0), " ", trim(utf8_decode($em->item(0)->textContent)));
            $ads['currency'] = $currency.'.';
            $strongObjs->item(0)->removeChild($em->item(0));
        }
        if ($strongObjs->length > 0) { // price
            $price = str_replace(chr(0xC2).chr(0xA0), "", trim(utf8_decode($strongObjs->item(0)->textContent)));
            $ads['price'] = $price;
        }
        ...
    return $ads;
}
```

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Забыл написать, что результат вывожу с помощью `var_dump(...), print_r(...)` и в эксель (через phpexcel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($html,'HTML-ENTITIES','UTF-8'));
```

И далее по коду не используйте преобразования кодировок.

Comment: Помогло. Спасибо!